# iOS Emulator Crash on Sign-In Button Click in Flutter App

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, ios-simulator

I am encountering a persistent issue while attempting to open my Flutter app on the iOS emulator. The problem arises when I click on the "Sign In with Google" or any other button in the app, causing an immediate crash. I have already executed flutter doctor, and no issues were reported.

To provide more context and aid in troubleshooting, I am willing to share additional code files if needed. Please let me know which files or sections of code would be most helpful for diagnosing and resolving this problem. I am seeking guidance on identifying the root cause of the crash and implementing a solution.

Any insights, suggestions, or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
Incident Identifier: 79A66427-9DCF-4D90-B160-93757D95DA7B
CrashReporter Key:   8ECF55FE-91AD-021D-3A1A-2CD283C69157
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro18,3
Process:             Runner [22592]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BD1A0D1B-10E2-4720-AED3-ADA72DFDCA94/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/41829695-9B02-47EC-8380-6AF196D2267F/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.example.tiffsyApp
Version:             1.0.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [14954]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.BD1A0D1B-10E2-4720-AED3-ADA72DFDCA94 [1731]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1061]

Date/Time:           2024-01-17 09:20:55.9962 +0530
Launch Time:         2024-01-17 09:20:40.1719 +0530
OS Version:          macOS 14.2.1 (23C71)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Runner [22592]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x18049111c __exceptionPreprocess + 160
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x18008412c objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180491038 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   GoogleSignIn                           0x1042bf3a4 -[GIDSignIn assertValidParameters] + 156 (GIDSignIn.m:988)
4   GoogleSignIn                           0x1042bbbd4 -[GIDSignIn signInWithOptions:] + 112 (GIDSignIn.m:519)
5   GoogleSignIn                           0x1042ba924 -[GIDSignIn signInWithConfiguration:presentingViewController:hint:additionalScopes:callback:] + 228 (GIDSignIn.m:242)
6   Runner                                 0x1030011fc -[FLTGoogleSignInPlugin signInWithCompletion:] + 528
7   Runner                                 0x103006090 __FSIGoogleSignInApiSetup_block_invoke.119 + 184
8   Flutter                                0x10e24192c __48-[FlutterBasicMessageChannel setMessageHandler:]_block_invoke + 160
9   Flutter                                0x10dc6078c invocation function for block in flutter::PlatformMessageHandlerIos::HandlePlatformMessage(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<flutter::PlatformMessage, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<flutter::PlatformMessage>>) + 108
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18016b4f4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18016cd3c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18017bb24 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1272
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18017b61c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
14  CoreFoundation                         0x1803f1a30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
15  CoreFoundation                         0x1803ec148 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
16  CoreFoundation                         0x1803eb5a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
17  GraphicsServices                       0x18e9fbae4 GSEventRunModal + 160
18  UIKitCore                              0x1852f02e4 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
19  UIKitCore                              0x1852f3f5c UIApplicationMain + 124
20  Runner                                 0x102fad08c main + 64 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
21  dyld_sim                               0x1031f1544 start_sim + 20
22  dyld                                   0x1034160e0 start + 2360
23  ???                             0x111d800000000000 ???

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1044e49ec __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1045ef1d0 pthread_kill + 256
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1801605cc abort + 104
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18028ec78 abort_message + 128
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x180280198 demangling_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x18005fbf0 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18028e150 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18028e100 std::terminate() + 52
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18016cd50 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18017bb24 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1272
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18017b61c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
11  CoreFoundation                         0x1803f1a30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
12  CoreFoundation                         0x1803ec148 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
13  CoreFoundation                         0x1803eb5a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
14  GraphicsServices                       0x18e9fbae4 GSEventRunModal + 160
15  UIKitCore                              0x1852f02e4 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
16  UIKitCore                              0x1852f3f5c UIApplicationMain + 124
17  Runner                                 0x102fad08c main + 64 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
18  dyld_sim                               0x1031f1544 start_sim + 20
19  dyld                                   0x1034160e0 start + 2360

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1045ea6dc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1045ea6dc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1044dcbb0 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1044edd44 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1044e4dd4 mach_msg_overwrite + 532
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1044dcf28 mach_msg + 20
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1803f1754 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1803ebe34 __CFRunLoopRun + 1148
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1803eb5a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
7   Foundation                             0x180dcd68c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 208
8   Foundation                             0x180dcd8b0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 60
9   UIKitCore                              0x185393b88 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 404
10  Foundation                             0x180df3e70 __NSThread__start__ + 720
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1045ef4c0 _pthread_start + 104
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1045ea6f0 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: Debug on actual device. Google sign in wont work on emulator

Comment: Have you added a reverse client ID from googleJson.plist file to info.plist file?